# why I can't inject child bean class of not bean abstract parent class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, inheritance, cdi, weld

I have a parametrized abstract class with one parametrized constructor:

```
public abstract class BasicEntidadController<T extends Entidad> implements Serializable {

     public BasicEntidadController(EntidadBean<T> entidadSessionBean) {....}
     // other methods
}
```

and a child class extending it:

```
@SessionScoped
@Named
public class TiendaController extends BasicEntidadController<Tienda> implements Serializable {...}
```

and WELD reports an error telling me that "BasicEntidadController" is not proxyable....

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnproxyableResolutionException: WELD-001435 Normal scoped bean class org.wgualla.sandbox.entity.BasicEntidadController is not proxyable because it has no no-args constructor - Managed Bean [class org.wgualla.sandbox.tienda.TiendaController] with qualifiers [@Any @Default @Named].
```

Why WELD is trying to create a proxy of this abstract/no-bean class???

Must I do all classes, in inheritance tree, proxyables if I want to inject/use in EL expresion just the last child in the tree?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The exception message mentions - *Managed Bean [class org.wgualla.sandbox.tienda.TiendaController]* and the complaint is - *has no no-args constructor*. May be the message is not so straight forward but try adding a no-arg constructor.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is the easy way. I could want to know why weld is trying to create a proxy if this class is abstract and never will be instanciated.

Comment: because anything that is eligible for injection needs to follow the requirements.  It's one of those gotchas around CDI and managed beans.

Comment: this means that I can't have a class that does not meet the requirements of the CDI within the entire project?

Comment: Within the class hierarchy, no.  You could veto that underlying class as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

By definition a java bean has "The class must have a public default constructor (with no arguments)."

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBeans_API

I would suggest that you change your constructor to

```
public BasicEntidadController() {....}
     // other methods
```

and then add a setter method

```
setEntidadSessionBean(EntidadBean<T> entidadSessionBean)
```

Or even better - read about dependancy injection. You can then use something like

```
@Autowired
EntidadBean<T> entidadSessionBean;
```

See http://www.vogella.com/articles/SpringDependencyInjection/

Hope this helps